# Excel run time 429 error on all computers

Tags: vba, runtime-error, activex

Error " Active x component can't create object"  Was working until a few weeks back.  Now doesn't work on any computer  - the workbook hasn't changed and no version of it works.    Using office 360 excel 2016.  Have tried uninstall and repair.  I'm a super novice abut have been reading articles here which suggest that I perhaps have a DLL problem but I'm not sure where to even start.

Comment: What changed a few weeks back? A software update?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that is a problem with a missing component, try to open the vba code and check the references.